# JPQL query for timestamp

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am creating a batch job using the JpaPagingItemReader
and my query looks like this in the job configuration:

```
<property name="queryString" value="SELECT a FROM EntityName a
                                        WHERE a.status = 'RUNNING'
                                        AND a.validTo = '2017-12-13'"/>
```

when I execute the job I receive the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

how can I pass the correct format to the query to fetch from the database? the the column in the database is a timestamp in normal sql I would do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM EntityName
WHERE VALID_TO = to_timestamp('2017-12-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: I wonder what JAVA TYPE is "validTo" field ...

Comment: It's a LocalDate

Comment: so why are you comparing a TIMESTAMP/DATE field with a text string? use a LocalDate as parameter

Comment: how can I pass a LocalDate as a parameter?

Comment: Change the JPQL to `SELECT a FROM EntityName a WHERE a.status = 'RUNNING' AND a.validTo = :myParam`, like any JPA documentation would tell you, and pass the parameter in

Answer (score 0):

JPQL follows the syntax of SQL and JDBC for date literals:

```
Date - {d 'yyyy-mm-dd'} - for example: {d '2010-12-31'}
Time - {t 'hh:mm:ss'} - for example: {t '23:59:59'}
Timestamp - {ts 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'} - for example: {ts '2011-01-03 14:59:59'}
```